# how to find subsets from given sets like below

Tags: python, list, set, tuples, subset

How to make program for getting subset if given list is [1,2,3] and output should be [[1], [2], [3], [1,2], [2,3], [1,3], [1,2,3]]. That is how to get all possible combinations?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools

arr = [1, 2, 3] 
res = []

for i in range(len(arr)):
  combinations = itertools.combinations(arr, i + 1)
  for c in combinations:
    res.append(list(c))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way to do it **without using Itertools.combination.**

```
l=[1,2,3]
all_comb=[]
x=len(l)
for i in range(1,1 << x):
    all_comb.append([l[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))])
all_comb
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this: (inList is your input list and outList is your output list)

```
import itertools
outList = []

def subs(S, m):
    return set(itertools.combinations(S, m))

outList = []
for i in range(0, len(inList),1):
    outList += subs(inList, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `itertools.combinations`, you can also achieve it through pure python code;

```
nums=[1,2,3]
sublist=[]
for i in range (len(nums)+1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(nums)+1):
        sub=nums[i:j]
        sublist.append(sub)
print(sublist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

input_set = [1, 2, 3]
subsets = []

for i in range(len(input_set)+1):
    combinations = itertools.combinations(input_set, i)
    for c in combinations:
        subsets.append(list(c))

print(subsets)
```

Comment: code is simple to understand as well it include empty set